# query object from ES

Tags: elasticsearch

I have below ES mapping

```
 "students" : {
          "properties" : {
            "tag" : {
              "type" : "nested",
              "properties" : {
                "id" : {
                  "type" : "keyword"
                },
                "name" : {
                  "type" : "text"
                }
              }
            },
```

how do I query from students->tag->id since `students` is not defined as nested.

I need a query which can support more than one id to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "students.tag",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "students.tag.id": "1234"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not getting any response

Comment: Please update your question with a sample document that you think should be returned